# Download file linked in MySQL DB, extract text and insert into db with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to download a file (only download if the url ends with a certain string), which URL is in a MySQL database, extract the text and write the text to the database, by replacing the url. 
And this have to be done for every row (approx. 25k rows).

Is there a way to do this with a bash script (or something else e.g Java)?

The MySQL server runs on my linux root, I have full access to it. My desktop OS is also linux (Linux Mint with many customizations).

This is what I made so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++))
do

   DBQUERY=`mysql -B -ss -uuser -ppassword -e "USE table; SELECT column FROM table WHERE pid='$i';"`

   if [[ $DBQUERY == *.pls ]] ;
   then
        wget -O tempfile.pls $DBQUERY
        while read line
        do
            if [[ $line == File1=* ]] ;
            then
                mysql -B -ss -uuser -ppassword -e "USE table; UPDATE table SET column = '${line:6}' WHERE pid = '$i';"
            fi
        done <tempfile.pls
   fi
done
```

How can I secure it?

Comment: What did you try so far and where exactly did you get stuck? Can you query the DB? Can you save the URLs to a file? Can you download the target? Can you insert data from a text file in the DB?

Comment: I'm confused as to what is it that you are trying to replace.  Text in the URL or text in the file?

Comment: I want to replace the url in the db with the content of the file.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your script but the most important one is that you are blindly trusting data from a remote website.  Even a simple unescaped `';` in the txt could update ALL records in the database.  and much worse could be done if the remote data was designed to be malicious rather than just accidental.  I **strongly recommend** you look into using `Perl` and `DBI` or `Python` and `SQLAlchemy` or similar for database work rather than trying to DIY in bash.  In particular, you want to use placeholders for all variables being passed to SQL select/insert/update/etc queries.

Comment: as an added bonus, both perl and python have good web robot libraries to help automate downloading and extracting data from remote URLs.

Comment: Hmm. I never used `Perl` or `Python`. The files in the database are maintained buy someone and are only playlist files. I don't think they're malicious.

Comment: My script work. Is there a way to secure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe, you have to look at the generated, if code can be injected.

In this command `mysql -B -ss -uuser -ppassword -e "USE table; SELECT column FROM table WHERE pid='$i';"`, you know that i is a number between 1 and 5 so it's ok.

But in that command `mysql -B -ss -uuser -ppassword -e "USE table; UPDATE table SET column = '${line:6}' WHERE pid = '$i';"`, you cannot be sure of ${line:6}; you can imagine it contains a single quote, in this case you have to replace by two single quotes, you can also check the length is less than the length of the column in database (let's suppose here 255) or truncate the data, before replacing quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++))
do
  DBQUERY=`mysql -B -ss -uuser -ppassword -e "USE table; SELECT column FROM table WHERE pid='$i';"`
  if [[ $DBQUERY == *.pls ]] ;
  then
    wget -O tempfile.pls $DBQUERY
    while read line
    do
      if [[ $line == File1=* ]] ;
      then
        str=${line:6:255}
        str=${str//\'/''}
        mysql -B -ss -uuser -ppassword -e "USE table; UPDATE table SET column = '$str' WHERE pid = '$i';"
      fi
    done <tempfile.pls
  fi
done
```